# Nginx config, how can I redirect primary multisite domain, but not its sub-folders, nor other domains?

Tags: multisite, redirect, nginx

### Environment

This environment is Nginx with Wordpress Multisite installed.

### Question

I need to redirect the primary multisite domain (e.g. domain.com, www.domain.com) to another domain (e.g. domain-new.com, www.domain-new.com). But I don't want sub-folders to redirect. For example, the /wp-admin/ folders needs to NOT redirect, otherwise I'll be unable to administer the multisite network.

Obviously, I don't want any other domains to redirect. Just the one stated above.

I found instructions on how to do this in Apache, but I haven't been able to figure it out in Nginx.

### What I came up with so far

I came across the following:

```
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name domain.com www.domain.com;
  rewrite ^ $scheme://www.domain-new.com$request_uri permanent;
```

But this will also redirect sub-folders of domain.com. I was to sure how to make it exclude `wp-admin` folder from the redirection.

I also came across this option:

```
location = / {
rewrite ^ http://domain-new.com/$uri permanent;    
}
```

But I couldn't find anything on whether the `location` command can include a domain, and if it can, how to ensure a specific sub-folder (`wp-admin`) is not included in the redirect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your `nginx` server block is handling multiple domains, the simplest solution would be to test the `$host` parameter within an `if` block. Also, change the `rewrite` statement so that it only matches a single URI.

For example:

```
if ($host = domain.com) {
    rewrite ^/$ https://new-domain.com permanent;
}
```

This is placed near the top of the existing `server` block.

Comment: (I deleted my prior two comments. At first I thought this didn't work, because it caused issues. But I discovered those issues were due to a missing `;` in a prior line of code). This solution is working just fine. Thank you.